# Creating Select statement with variable in single quotes

Tags: select, google-fusion-tables

This relates to taking data from a Google Fusion table.

When I first set up my site, GF tableid was a **numeric** value, (var tableid = 123456;) and I built a query like this:

```
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Name' contains etc etc
```

Now tableid is something like var `tableid = '12DFty24';` and I'm having trouble converting the setQuery to handle it.

I've tried adding an extra single quote around tableid, but that doesn't work. Nor do backslashes.

Ideas would be gratefully received!

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's the one that works...need to be careful with parentheses and commas!

```
function searchAddress()   
{
  var searchString = document.getElementById('searchAddressString').value.replace("'", "\\'");
 //  layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Address' contains ignoring case '" + searchString + "'");
  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: 'Latitude',
    from: tableid,
    where: 'Address' contains ignoring case '" + searchString + "'" 
   }
 }); 
layer.setMap(map);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old syntax that can't work with encrypted ID, numeric ID's are [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fusion-tables-api-announce/_KI_HnWT9V4/S-ZeAYC2zkoJ).

You have to change your code using the new syntax; here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer)

Example:

```
new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ query: {[FusionTablesQuery object]}});
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But I'm really looking for an example to follow. The doco is a bit sparse...